# Case Optimization

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

We have a common case that is used to calculate the work shift. Sometimes we use it inside a function, other times direct in the code. It depends on the age of the code.

My question is, there is a more efficient way to implement these Case?

Create a calculated column is not an option because the times come from a lot of tables different, and most of them are tables that we can not change.

This is the example code

**Function**

```
Create Function dbo.wShift(@wTime datetime) 
Returns varchar(21)
AS
Begin
    Return  case 
            when DATEPART(weekday,@wTime) between 2 and 6 and cast(@wTime as time) between cast('8:30' as time)  and cast('16:30' as time) then 'MON_FRI_8:30-16:30' 
            when DATEPART(weekday,@wTime) = 6 and cast(@wTime as time) >=  cast('16:30' as time)  
              or DATEPART(weekday,@wTime) = 2 and cast(@wTime as time) <=  cast('8:30' as time) then 'FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30'
            when DATEPART(weekday,@wTime) in (1,7) then 'FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30'         
            else 'MON_FRI_16:30-8:30' end;
END 
GO
```

**Sample Data and Expected Result**

```
Declare @shiftTimes table (MyDate datetime, eShift varchar(23) )
INSERT @shiftTimes values 
 ('2017-01-02 08:31:46.843' ,'MON_FRI_8:30-16:30')
,('2017-01-03 10:35:21.263' ,'MON_FRI_8:30-16:30')
,('2017-04-14 17:24:14.900' ,'FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30')
,('2017-01-06 16:30:51.223' ,'FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30')
,('2017-01-01 00:24:47.450' ,'FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30')
,('2017-01-08 14:22:08.920' ,'FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30')
,('2017-01-02 00:24:11.190' ,'FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30')
,('2017-04-17 07:15:15.650' ,'FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30')
,('2017-01-02 16:38:30.860' ,'MON_FRI_16:30-8:30')
,('2017-01-11 06:27:01.017' ,'MON_FRI_16:30-8:30')
```

**Direct implementation of the Case in the query and test code**

```
;WITH Cte as
(
    SELECT 
         MyDate
        ,eShift
        ,dbo.wShift(Mydate) wShiftFunction
        ,case 
            when DATEPART(weekday,MyDate) between 2 and 6 and cast(MyDate as time) between cast('8:30' as time)  and cast('16:30' as time) then 'MON_FRI_8:30-16:30' 
            when DATEPART(weekday,MyDate) = 6 and cast(MyDate as time) >=  cast('16:30' as time)  
            or DATEPART(weekday,MyDate) = 2 and cast(MyDate as time) <=  cast('8:30' as time) then 'FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30'
            when DATEPART(weekday,MyDate) in (1,7) then 'FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30'         
            else 'MON_FRI_16:30-8:30'
        end wShiftCase
    FROM @shiftTimes
)
SELECT
     MyDate
    ,eShift
    ,wShiftFunction
    ,wShiftCase
    ,CASE WHEN eShift = wShiftFunction THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NOK' END Check_wShiftFunction
    ,CASE WHEN eShift = wShiftCase THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NOK' END Check_wShiftCase
FROM
    cte
```

Comment: What difference between `MON_FRI_16:30-8:30` and `FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30`?

Comment: MON_FRI_16:30-8:30 is the overtime in weekdays between 16:30 and 8:30 the next day. FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30 is the overtime starting on Friday 16:30 and finishing on Monday 8:30

Comment: Why a scalar function here? This should be an inline table valued function instead.

Comment: @SeanLange. I did not try this approach. When I created this function, I had thought of the easier use to junior team member uses it was a scalar function.

Comment: I would caution against using code that is known to be slow so that a junior team member can write code easier. If anything it is teaching your junior that scalar functions are ok. They should be avoided when possible (which is most of the time) in favor of things like table valued functions to maintain high performing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the reason for your question is that queries using this are slow. This is the nature of scalar functions. Convert this to an inline table valued function and see how much the performance changes. Something like this.

```
Create Function dbo.wShift(@wTime datetime) 
Returns table 
AS
    Return  select eShift = case 
            when DATEPART(weekday,@wTime) between 2 and 6 and cast(@wTime as time) between cast('8:30' as time)  and cast('16:30' as time) then 'MON_FRI_8:30-16:30' 
            when DATEPART(weekday,@wTime) = 6 and cast(@wTime as time) >=  cast('16:30' as time)  
              or DATEPART(weekday,@wTime) = 2 and cast(@wTime as time) <=  cast('8:30' as time) then 'FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30'
            when DATEPART(weekday,@wTime) in (1,7) then 'FRI-16:30 to MON-8:30'         
            else 'MON_FRI_16:30-8:30' end;
GO
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I tested the solution with one report, and I got those times: table-valued function: 1146 ms; direct case statement: 1147 ms; scalar function 2170 ms